# XmlTextReader with SslStream - reading multiple xml from stream

Tags: c#, .net, xml, sockets, ssl

I have an SslStream from which I receive spontaneous XML messages. I want to use XmlTextReader to process XML messages from that stream. Unfortunately it allows me reading only 1st XML. When I call Read after the 1st xml is received, the method throws an exception:
Multiple roots in XML documents ("Xml_MultipleRoots"). I believe this is a problem that the stream provides xml messages one by one but the XmlTextReader can handle only one.
How to fix this?

Comment: Isn't there a separation char between xmls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, don't use `new XmlTextReader()` anymore. Use `XmlReader.Create()`, which has been the preferred way to create an `XmlReader` since .NET 2.0.

Second, use the overload of `Create` that accepts an `XmlReaderSettings` object:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(sslStream, 
                                     new XmlReaderSettings
                                         {
                                             ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment
                                         }))
{
// ... read xml
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new XmlReader around the stream for each message.

Comment: The problem is the Ssl is a stream so with one Read operation not all the data for one XML document may be received at once. I end up with exception saying unexpected EOF.